# Rounding all numbers in 2D array except main diagonals in C

Tags: c, arrays

i got a problem, i cant understand how to get all numbers in 2d array rounded, except two main diagonals. Right now i have working code to round all elements witch are in those two diagonals, except all other. But i need to round all other elements witch are not in diagonals. its a square array.

```
`void diog(int a) {
float dio1, dio2;
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < a; j++){
    dio1=masivs[i][i];
    dio1 = round (masivs[i][i]);
    masivs[i][i] = dio1;
    dio2= masivs[i][a - i - 1];
    dio2= round (masivs[i][a - i - 1]);
    masivs[i][a - i - 1] = dio2;
    cout << masivs[i][j] << " ";
}
}
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void diog(int a) 
{
    float dio1;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
        {
            if ((i!=j) && (i!=a-1-j))
            {
                dio1 = round (masivs[i][j]);
                masivs[i][j] = dio1;
            }   
            cout << masivs[i][j] << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code works, but it only excludes one main diagonal. I need both diagonals to  be excluded. And it prints only rounded elements. I need to print all elements in array. But only round elements which are not in diagonals.

Comment: @Starix Simply write a second, down-counting loop that counts from the opposite direction?